# How to {pivot|denormalize|manipulate} CSV table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the messy title, I didn't know how to phrase this question well.

Let's say I have a table in which the first three columns are foo bar and baz. Then there are some number of arbitrary columns after. I want to manipulate the table such that these arbitrary columns are all collapsed under on column, called num.

An example makes this clearer

```
foo, bar, baz, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104,
1,   1,   1,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,
1,   1,   2,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,
1,   2,   1,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,
```

This input should transpose to:

```
num, foo, bar, baz, value,
100,   1,    1,  1,    10,
100,   1,    1,  2,    15,
100,   1,    2,  1,    20,
101,   1,    1,  1,    11,
101,   1,    1,  2,    16,
101,   1,    2,  1,    21,
102,   1,    1,  1,    12,
102,   1,    1,  2,    17,
102,   1,    2,  1,    22,
...
```

I wrote a custom Python solution that does this. It wasn't hard, but I feel like this is reinventing the wheel.

Is there a way to accomplish this with a library like pandas or some other table manipulation module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
res = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])

print(res)

    foo  bar  baz variable  value
0     1    1    1      100     10
1     1    1    2      100     15
2     1    2    1      100     20
3     1    1    1      101     11
4     1    1    2      101     16
5     1    2    1      101     21
6     1    1    1      102     12
7     1    1    2      102     17
8     1    2    1      102     22
9     1    1    1      103     13
10    1    1    2      103     18
11    1    2    1      103     23
12    1    1    1      104     14
13    1    1    2      104     19
14    1    2    1      104     24
```

Comment: Can this really be the first question we've had over the last few years with a one-line pandas.melt answer?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
cols = np.concatenate([['num'], df.columns[:3], ['value']])
pd.DataFrame([
    [a, b, c, d, e]
    for b, c, d, *x in df.values
    for a, e in zip(df.columns[3:], x)
]).set_axis(cols, axis=1, inplace=False).sort_values('num')

    num  foo  bar  baz  value
0   100    1    1    1     10
5   100    1    1    2     15
10  100    1    2    1     20
1   101    1    1    1     11
6   101    1    1    2     16
11  101    1    2    1     21
2   102    1    1    1     12
7   102    1    1    2     17
12  102    1    2    1     22
3   103    1    1    1     13
8   103    1    1    2     18
13  103    1    2    1     23
4   104    1    1    1     14
9   104    1    1    2     19
14  104    1    2    1     24
```

Comment: I may be going with a theme today (-:

Answer (score 2):

You can use dataframe reshaping with `set_index`, `stack` and some column renaming:

```
(df.set_index(['foo','bar','baz'])
   .stack()
   .reset_index(name='value')
   .rename(columns={'level_3':'num'}))
```

Output:

```
    foo  bar  baz  num  value
0     1    1    1  100     10
1     1    1    1  101     11
2     1    1    1  102     12
3     1    1    1  103     13
4     1    1    1  104     14
5     1    1    2  100     15
6     1    1    2  101     16
7     1    1    2  102     17
8     1    1    2  103     18
9     1    1    2  104     19
10    1    2    1  100     20
11    1    2    1  101     21
12    1    2    1  102     22
13    1    2    1  103     23
14    1    2    1  104     24
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned above, [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) is the best way to do it !

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo' : np.random.randint(low = 0, high=5, size = 3), 'bar' : 
                  np.random.randint(low = 0, high=5, size = 3),'baz' : 
                  np.random.randint(low = 0, high=5, size = 3)})

for i in range(100,105):
df['%d'%i] = np.random.randint(low = 10, high=20, size = 3)

print(df) 
   foo  bar  baz  100  101  102  103  104
0    2    1    4   16   14   13   16   11
1    3    0    4   11   17   12   15   18
2    4    1    1   13   15   11   18   17
```

And now, the main function :

```
pd.melt(frame=df, id_vars= ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], value_vars= ['%d'%i for i in 
range(100,105)])

#output
   foo  bar baz variable  value
0   2   1   4   100        16
1   3   0   4   100        11
2   4   1   1   100        13
3   2   1   4   101        14
4   3   0   4   101        17
5   4   1   1   101        15
6   2   1   4   102        13
7   3   0   4   102        12
8   4   1   1   102        11
9   2   1   4   103        16
10  3   0   4   103        15
11  4   1   1   103        18
12  2   1   4   104        11
13  3   0   4   104        18
14  4   1   1   104        17
```